# Module build failed: Duplicate declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design Framework for my React project. But when importing components, it yells an error even though I haven't declared those components before.

ERROR:

```
Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "Icon"
```

Here is the code:

```js
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { FullSpinner } from "./Spinner"

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>sdkfjsdf</div>)
  }
}

export default App
```

```js
// Spinner.js

import { Spin, Icon } from 'antd';

import React from 'react'
import {Icon, Spin} from 'antd';

const antIcon = () => <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;


export const FullSpinner = () => <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported `Icon` component multiple times.

```
// Spinner.js

import { Spin, Icon } from 'antd';
import React from 'react'
import {Icon, Spin} from 'antd';  <- Duplicate

const antIcon = () => <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;
export const FullSpinner = () => <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
```

Try after removing `import { Spin, Icon } from 'antd';` from **`Spinner.js`**

Answer (score 1):

Your `Spinner.js` file is importing the `Spin` and `Icon` twice from the `antd` module. You can safely remove one of those lines.

```
// Spinner.js

import React from 'react'
import {Icon, Spin} from 'antd';

const antIcon = () => <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;


export const FullSpinner = () => <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
```